# Converting a list of nested lists in binary tree

Tags: python, list, tree, binary-search-tree

In python, I have a list of nested lists that represents a binary tree:

```
L = [0, [[1, [2, 3]], [4, [5, 6]]]]
```

So the tree can be seen as follows:

```
        0
       /  \
      1    4
     /\    /\ 
    2  3  5  6
```

I now want to implement a function that takes as input a level of the tree and returns all the nodes of that level:

```
GetNodes(0) = 0
GetNodes(1) = [1,4]
GetNodes(2) = [2,3,5,6]
```

Is there an easy way to do this, avoiding a brutal search on all the nested lists of `L`?
Is there the possibility of a more standard management of binary trees in python, maybe converting my list of lists in something else?

Comment: see if this can help: https://github.com/joowani/binarytree

Comment: Note that you can build a tree by using `collections.defaultdict`: `def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)`. Accessing elements is done via `[some_element]`. Because you want all elements of a certain level I think there is no other way than to start from the very top and traverse the tree until the specified level (is that what you meant by "brute force"?).

Comment: It is known as level order traversing. Google it and you'll find plenty of answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a BFS. Will post code asap :)

Edit: Here you go

```
L = [0, [[1, [2, 3]], [4, [5, 6]]]]


def getLevel(k, tree):
    currentLevel = [tree[0]]
    nextLevel = tree[1]
    level = 1
    while level <= k:
        _currentLevel = []
        _nextLevel = []
        for subtree in nextLevel:
            if isinstance(subtree, list):
                _currentLevel.append(subtree[0])
                if isinstance(subtree[1], list):
                    _nextLevel.append(subtree[1])
                else:
                    _currentLevel.append(subtree[1])
            else:
                _currentLevel.append(subtree)
        currentLevel= _currentLevel
        nextLevel = _nextLevel
        level+=1
    return currentLevel


# uncomment for python 2
# print getLevel(0, L)
# print getLevel(1, L)
# print getLevel(2, L)

# uncomment python 3
print(getLevel(0, L))
print(getLevel(1, L))
print(getLevel(2, L))
```

Answer (score 4):

my solution would parse into dict

```
l = [0, [[1, [2, 3, [[7,8], [10,11]]]], [4, [5, 6, [9,10]]]]]
datadict = {}

def toTree(data,depth=0):
    for elem in data:
        if not isinstance(elem, int):
            toTree(elem, depth+1)
        else:
            d = depth - 1 if depth > 0 else depth
            if datadict.get(d):
                datadict[d] = datadict[d] + [elem]
            else:
                datadict[d] = [elem]

toTree(l)
print(datadict)
```

the output would be

> {0: [0], 1: [1, 4], 2: [2, 3, 5, 6], 3: [9, 10], 4: [7, 8, 10, 11]}

and you can just use datadict.get(2) to get [2, 3, 5, 6]