# Module for plotting decision tree in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, pyqt5, decision-tree

I would like to ask how to plot a decision tree in python. The functionality which I mean is similar to one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564604/converting-a-list-of-nested-lists-in-binary-tree), but a picture is needed, not just text format.

For example, having this dictionary structure

```
MyNodeStructure = {'main': {'load': {'regA': None},
                            'comupute': {'loop': {'regA': None,
                                                  'regB': None}},
                            'store': None}}
```

I would like to get something like this as an output:
[Example of desired tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lADfQ.png).

Do you know any module/easy way how to achieve this result in Python3?

Comment: Most likely pydot is what you're after. See this question + answer for discussion of making a pydot pic from a dict: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657384/plotting-a-decision-tree-with-pydot

Comment: @greg_data Oh, pretty much what I wanted, except few insignificant details. I must have overlooked that question, thank you!